# Track account type (free/paid) in Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

We have an Android app which has some trial use time, and after that, user should buy the app with in-app purchase.

And I want to know, how to measure it with Google Analytics:

- What's the best way to track the account type? Metric, dimension, variable? I don't event know what is what, and couldn't find any clear explanation (ELI5 way) in the docs.
- How can I track in-app purchase which converts the account type from free to paid? I expected there to be some kind of API between Google Billing and Analytics, but I couldn't find any.
- How can I actually perform some analysis on the data? Get the conversion rate, ratio between free and paid accounts, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Each of your questions deserves a long explanation, but I will try to give you the best clues for you to start from:

- To track the account type I would use a [user-level scope custom dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#example-user). Values will be either "free" or "paid", or whatever value makes sense for you. That will allow you to [segment](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3124493?hl=en) your users and compare them.
- The cannonical way should be to track in-app purchases with [ecommerce tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/enhanced-ecommerce) (there are specific documentation for each SDK). As a general rule, you will trigger the transaction event after the payment is made (I guess there is a callback or something similar). By using the ecommerce module, you will take advantage of native Google Analytics reports, and you could even optimize whatever kind of funnel you have. You will also trigger at the same time the new custom dimension value.
- Both analysis will be possible if you follow these recommendations; a) the conversion rate will be available as part of the ecommerce report; b) you will be able to create two segments (one for 'free', other for 'paid') which shows what percentage of users belong to each.

By the way, I am not even sure that you really need to use custom dimensions, since you can create the user segments free/paid using only the available information from ecommerce (if user has transactions, then it is "paid"; if user has no transaction, then it is "free").

I hope it helps!